# enzyme mount fails when there is a function call in the componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, sinon, enzyme

I have a react component and in there I have a click function as follows:

```
    clickTwitter(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    let storyId = this.refs.storyToTweet.getAttribute('id');
    if (storyId != undefined) {
        let storyIdValue = this.props.storyId;
        this.postOnTwitter(storyIdValue);
    }
}
```

and in componentDidMount I have the following:

```
    componentDidMount(){
    this.fbInit();
}

fbInit(){
    return facebookInitializer= function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12&appId=${FACEBOOK.appId}&autoLogAppEvents=1`;
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');

}
```

I have the following test case:

```
        it('should call the clickTwitter method once', () => {
        // creates the spy for the clickTwitter method
        let clickTwitterSpy = sinon.spy(StoryMedia.prototype, 'clickTwitter');
        let props={

        }
        // wraps the component by using the enzyme mount method
        const wrapper = mount(<StoryMedia/>);

        // simulates a user clicking the twitter button
        wrapper.find('.shareTwitterDummy').simulate('click');
        // asserts that the clickTwitter method was called once when the button was clicked
        assert.strictEqual(StoryMedia.prototype.clickTwitter.calledOnce, true);
        // restores the method to its original state
        clickTwitterSpy.restore();
    });
```

when I run the test I get the following strange error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined....
```

If I remove the this.fbInit(); from componentDidMount everything works.
Is there anyway I can tell the test to ignore the this.fbInit()? Or any other solution is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that `var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];` fjs is `undefined`

Comment: How can I avoid it?

Comment: I don't know what you want with `fjs`